# Delete User when he leaves the Page but not on refresh

Tags: javascript, reload

I am building a Chatroom Website with multiple Rooms and I want to delete a user from my Database when he leaves one of the Rooms but not if he is refreshing the page.

The most common answer I read was using sessionStorage but as far as I know they would keep the value if someone leaves a Room (but not the page) and joins another Room

I am adding the user to the Database with this code when he joins a room:

```
if (!window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation').map((nav) => nav.type).includes('reload')) {
    addUserToDatabase();
}
```

and I want to delete the user with something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if (/* Is not about to reload */){
        deleteUserFromDatabase();
    }
}
```

Any Javascript/JQuery Solution would be fine.

Comment: _"but as far as I know they would keep the value if someone leaves a Room (but not the page) and joins another Room"_ - so set a _new_ value then, when they enter a different room?

Comment: _"when he leaves one of the Rooms"_ - so what does "leaving" one of those rooms actually look like then? Just clicking on some link to go to a different page, or what exactly?

Comment: Usually, things like that are implemented in a different way. For chat there should be some sort of bidirectional communication happening between server and client (or client and client if you have p2p). So you remove user when you don't receive a heartbeat. Image how you would handle user loosing network connection if you rely on client sending you notification to remove the user from DB?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Im using Websockets with Node.js and Socket.io because I heard a heartbeat would be inefficent

Comment: @CBroe My URLs look like this: localhost/chatroom/… Depending on the controller a "view" is included. For example for Room that would be a generic Room Template filled with data depending on the room name. Leaving a room would be going to controller=Foyer which is my start page

Comment: Well, socket.io still uses heartbeats ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ to detect connection lost, so not sure "inefficient" for what. But anyway having socket.io you could use "disconnected" event on your server to remove user from DB.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko but wouldnt that disconnect event also trigger on reload?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I had an AJAX Request every second to check if a user is still online but my task was to make the Server notify the clients when a client leaves the room. I thought this was about performance.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a less-discussed way: try to use [Sharedworker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) or [ServiceWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API), which can share a same context acorss same origin tabs, and you can keep somehow hearbeat between the tabs and the worker, in order to sync current-connecting roomId in a centralized way.

And when any/all tab closed, the worker should sense it and tell your server to do DB job.

By the way, you do have to handle the edge cases when the user's network turns offline, or user turns off computer suddenly and so on. I recommand you to make some heartbeat mechanism and disconnection reconnection mechanism, between web and your server.

Comment: Im using Node.js and Socket.io. When a user leaves he emits a signal to the server and the server sends back a signal to all clients that the user left. But for the initial "user leaves" signal same problem I need to tell the difference between about to reload and about to close to send the signal

Comment: Can these Workers also sense if that back button on the browser was pressed?

Comment: You can view it in a different way. Every time a tab loaded, it will register to the  worker, to declare the user is in the room. And every time a tab trigger unload, it will send message to the worker,but the worker will not trigger signal to your nodejs immediately. Actually it will wait until like 5 seconds, if no more register message send, it will trigger left-signal finally. @MRVN

Comment: So am I understanding that right? I will have a Worker that will register every User and if a user disconnects I will wait 5 seconds and if that user doesn't rejoin in 5 seconds I will delete that user from the DB